# AngularJS ng-click with data-toggle

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have a list item which toggles modal and sets a param using ng-click
the problem is when calling a function in any other place which logs `Course.SelectedCourse` it's undefined although `Course.ID` has a value.

```
<li class="facebook" style="width:33%;">
   <a ng-click="Course.SelectedCourse = Course.ID" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
   </a>
</li>
```

Comment: This take place also after you selected one item of the list, or only the first time when you not yet click a button?

Comment: i clicks that button which opens a modal that has a button that calls a function "dummyfun(Course.SelectedCourse)" where i log (Course.SelectedCourse)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a function in the controller, this might look like this :

In the view :

```
<li class="facebook" style="width:33%;" >
  <a ng-click="setSelectedCourse(Course.ID)" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
  </a>
</li>
```

In the controller

```
function setSelectedCourse(course_id){
  $scope.Course.SelectedCourse = course_id;
}
```

Comment: It works for me. Does anyone have explanation for this behaviour ? What is the difference ? Why doesn't this work: `ng-click="Course.SelectedCourse = Course.ID"` ?

Answer (score 1):

In AngularJS, directives have their own scope, your list is generated with ng-repeat, isn't it ? That's why

```
"Course.SelectedCourse = Course.ID"
```

doesn't work, because inside the div ng-repeat is looping $scope.Course is created locally and isn't the same that the one in your main controller. Besides, functions from main controller can be called by directives, That's why the previous answer works.